# Linux - iptables - get YouTube streaming bytes usage

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, streaming

How do I get bytes usage using iptables for a particular IP, including YouTube streaming videos?

Currently, I am using the following IP tables rules to get data usage by IP address:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 192.168.10.10 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 192.168.10.10 -j ACCEPT
```

But it's not recognizing data usage by YouTube videos.

Comment: When you say "it's not recognizing data usage by YouTube videos" do you mean that the bandwidth counter when you do a `iptables -nvL` doesn't go up?

Comment: +1 for @Bratchley 's question... Also have you considered trying a daemon more specifically designed for this purpose like `vnstat`? `vnstat` runs in the background and records data transfer over time (generates reports of network usage)

Comment: yes @Bratchley.. i'm using `iptable -nvL`.. and its not showing bytes usage of streaming videos